# Countability of set $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Given $X$ set of all binary sequence. .i.e. set of all sequence whose terms are $0$ and $1$ only and

$Y=\{(x_n)\in X : x_n=1 \text{ for atmost finitely many n}\}$ then is $Y$ is countable?

This question is asked so many times here and in some of the answers provided i found they used sets $Y_k=\{(x_n): x_n=0 \forall n> k\}$ this sets are countable and as we know countable union of countable sets is countable. Hence $Y = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} Y_k$ is countable.

**But i have doubt that,** $Y ≠ \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} Y_k$
Because, if i consider sequence $(a_n)$ such that its **1st**  and **1000th** terms are $1$ and all other terms are $0$ then, $(a_n)$ is in $Y$ but it is not in $Y_n$? Please help....

Comment: I think you want $Y_k=\{(x_n)\,:\, x_n=0\forall n>k\}$ because, with "$\forall k>n$", $Y_k\nsubseteq Y$ in the first place.

Comment: @Gae.S. sir. yes thank you for notifying it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sequence that you mentioned belongs to $Y_{1\,000}$. So, there is no problem there.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I forgot that 1000th term and terms before 1000th term of sequences in $Y_{1000}$ are not fix they may either $1$ or $0$. So that sequence that i mentioned belongs to $Y_{1000}$.